# Advice on best practice for checking record falling between multiple dates

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, pseudocode

I'm looking to find out the most efficient pseudo-code in order to achieve the following conditions:

- I have an "event" which has a start and an end date (S1, S2)
- I am try to find out if this even occurs within a specific time-frame (D1, D2)
- If the event only lasts for one day, it will not have an end date
- I only want one occurrence of the event in the query.

If anybody is able to assist with tbe psuedo code behind such a query, I'd be grateful.

It's for use within a LINQ query.

Comment: if possible, try converting the date to numeric - would make comparisons a hell lot faster. you can either convert to unix time or yyyymmddhhmm format and then play around with >= and <= to achieve much better performance

Comment: LINQ to what? And why do you want to use event only once in the query?

Comment: "If the event only lasts for one day, it will not have an end date." Well, of course it will. It's not gonna last forever. Unless maybe it's something Congress is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the event over laps a specific time frame use

```
Event.Start < TimeFrame.End && (Event.End == null) ? Event.Start.AddDays(1) : Event.End > TimeFrame.Start
```

Comment: I tried this, however received the following error:

An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

return from objEvent in db.Events where ((objEvent.StartDate >= d1 && objEvent.StartDate <= d2) && (objEvent.EndDate >= DateTime.Now) && (objEvent.EventType1.Tag == eventtype)...

Comment: EntityFunctions.AddDays(Event.Start, 1)

Answer (score 1):

If you define (S1, S2) as (S1, S2?? S1) then

condition will be met if:

```
  S2 >= D1 && D2 >= S1




        S1     S2
        |------|  
D1                     D2
|-----------------------|

            S1                  S2
            |-------------------|  
    D1                     D2
    |-----------------------|

    S1                  S2
    |-------------------|  
              D1                       D2
              |-----------------------|


    S1                        S2
    |-------------------------|  
              D1      D2
              |-------|
```

But the condition will not be met for these:

```
        S1                  S2
        |-------------------|  
D1  D2
|----|

S1   S2
|-----|  
          D1                       D2
          |-----------------------|
```